# Вызвать команду на странице

Tags: javascript

Вопрос из серии "не знаю как загуглить"

Мне нужно в фоновом режиме уведомлять сайт о том, что я.. на нём нахожусь.

Сайт - web.telegram.org/ если после небольшого времени бездействия сделать любое действие (например, кликнуть по пустому пространству на сайте) то сразу отправятся команды `call account.updateStatus` и `call messages.readHistory`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно имитировать событие *присутствия* или просто вызвать `call messages.readHistory`?

P.S. Сайт открываю в приложении через браузер на хромиуме, т.е. у меня полный доступ к элементам, консоле и т.д.

Comment: А что за сайт? Про что он? "Не удается получить доступ к сайту" ))

Comment: Это веб-клиент для Telegram, включенный в реестр запрещённых ресурсов)

Comment: > Сайт открываю в приложении через браузер на хромиуме...
Т.е. это приложение со встроенным браузером, если я правильно понимаю? А что за обёртку вы используете? Если это electron, то может быть один способ, если другой инструмент, то и способ отличается.

Comment: @Dan CefSharp на C#, но не думаю, что это принципиально. Какие есть варианты впринципе?

Comment: Разница в том, какой мануал курить)
А вариант с пользовательским событием, описанный в вопросе, пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что вы пытаетесь сделать, то попробуйте этот вариант:

```
var script = "document.getElementById('buttonId').click()"; // кликнуть на нужном элементе страницы, выберите какой вам больше подходит         
browser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(script);
```

[Документация CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJS)

Comment: Уже пытался и кликать, и другие события вызывать, всё бестолку. Забавно, что таким способом можно читать сообщения не оставляя отметку о прочтении

Comment: Может быть, попробовать зайти-выйти из чата?